# SQL Query Between 2 Dates or first one before

Tags: mysql, sql, between

Ok so I want to find all the prices that were active in a period.
 I have a table "prices" with each price and the date it was activated.

```
╔══════════════╦═════════════════╗
║ price_number ║ activation_date ║
╠══════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ Price 1      ║ 2014-12-03      ║
║ Price 2      ║ 2014-12-07      ║
║ Price 3      ║ 2014-12-12      ║
║ Price 4      ║ 2014-12-25      ║
╚══════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Now I want to select the prices that were active between 2014-12-09 and 2014-12-14.

Price 2 and Price 3 should be displayed as a result (Price 2 because it was active between 2014-12-09 and 2014-12-12 until price 3 was activated).

So basically I want the prices with an activation date between 2014-12-09 and 2014-12-14 or the first one before the 2014-12-09.

What I got so far :

```
SELECT * FROM prices 
WHERE (activation_date BETWEEN '2014-12-09' AND '2014-12-14') 
OR (Something I can't find)
```

I'm working with MySQL 5.5

Comment: **or** the first one before or **and** the first one before? What if the previous price _ends_ inside the specified range?

Comment: 2nd option, AND the first one before if it ends inside my specific range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bit complicated, because of the conditionality on the previous row.  Here is one approach using `union all`:

```
(SELECT p.*
 FROM prices p
 WHERE activation_date BETWEEN '2014-12-09' AND '2014-12-14'
) UNION ALL
(SELECT p.*
 FROM prices p
 WHERE activation_date < '2014-12-09' AND
       NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM prices p2 WHERE activation_date BETWEEN '2014-12-09' AND '2014-12-14')
 ORDER BY activation_date DESC
 LIMIT 1
);
```

Comment: I slightly modified your answer because the output is only Price3 and i want price2 as well. I replaced with the following : NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM prices p2 WHERE activation_date = '2014-12-09') . If there is no price that has its activation date at the '2014-12-09', it means there is one previously activated.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate way would be ....

`select * from 
(
select p1.price_number,p1.activation_date, min(dateadd(day,datediff(day,p1.activation_date,p2.activation_date)-1,p1.activation_date)) 'activationdate_end' from prices p1
inner join prices p2 on p1.activation_date < p2.activation_date
group by p1.price_number,p1.activation_date
) A where ('2014-12-09' between A.activation_date and A.activationdate_end) or '2014-12-14' between A.activation_date and A.activationdate_end`

This is in MSSQL ... But I am sure it can also be done in MySQL

Comment: Nice approach, I like the way to calculate the end activation_date of each price. Few problems though, the last WHERE clause should be a little bit modified because if both activationdate and activationdate_end are between 2014-12-09 and 2014-12-14, then the condition returns false and it should return true. Also, change the INNER JOIN to a LEFT JOIN because if it's the currently active price, the activationdate_end should be NULL. Nice work. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for the left join suggestion. You are right..
But please notice that I have used the 'or' operator  instead of the 'and' operation.. So if one statement returns true the record will be included in the recordset

Comment: Example of my point : Imagine another price with activationdate = 2014-12-10 and activationdate_end = 2014-12-11. 2014-12-09 isn't between those 2 dates and neither is 2014-12-14. Or did I miss something ?